# Writing to kernel memory in kernel 3 versus kernel 2.4?

Tags: memory, data-structures, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've written a `LKM` which writes to a data structure of kernel `(poolinfo_table)`. If I `insmod` this `LKM` in `kernel 2.4` I guess it writes to this data structure, but when I do the same with `kernel 3.10` my system restarts as I expect! What's wrong with `kernel 2.4`? Its kernel memory isn't protected or I'm not actually writing to it?! I mean I expect any kernel crush when I try to writing to its memory, so I'm in doubt I've written actually to my kernel 2.4's memory. In fact I tried the same code at my host system (Fedora 18) with kernel 3.10 and my guest (Redhat 9) with kernel 2.4. (I have hypervisor Xen)

Comment: What is you goal here?  It sounds like you are hoping to crash the system by writing to random parts of kernel memory?  Obviously not *every* write to kernel memory from kernel context will cause a protection-based crash, as the kernel legitimately needs to write to its own data structures.  In terms of corruption-triggered crashes, randomly poking at things should not be expected to yield consistent results - you might change something that matters not a bit, or matters in only a trivial way or will not matter until more time has passed or other conditions cause corrupted data to be needed.

Comment: @Chris Stratton:I've written some integrity code for integrity of kerneldata structures.(some specific data structures in fact) so to test them I've tried to change them through lkm and surprisingly I see kernel 2.4 let me to modify data structures but kernel 3 won't. I just wanted to be sure that it's the matter of different kernels or I'm not touching kernel at all.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "let you modify?"  That the writes took effect?  Or that the kernel was not *obviously* impacted by the change *for some period of time*?  And I don't think anyone can give you a solid answer without knowing exactly what you changed.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton: The writes took effect and the kernel was obviously impacted by the change. I'm curious why there is no protection (in kernel 2.4) to not to let modify theses structures (as kernel 3 does).And if you want to know the modifications, for example I changed number of max_threads to a small number and it affected the system so that it didn't let me to fork any new process anymore!

Comment: What sort of "protection" are you claiming the newer kernel provided?

Comment: Linux 2.4 is a very old kernel to begin with. Why are you working with it anyway?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: yes exactly!

Comment: @tangrs:I know.just for practicing and learning purposes.

Comment: LKM ops was seriously changed in 3.6 kernel, I think it is impossible to use same routines in 2.4 (tooooo old :)) and 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

In userland if you write to somewhere that you are not supposed to (somewhere in your address space that's not writeable, maybe it's not mapped or maybe it's write protected for example) the mmu may issue a bus error or segmentation violation to your process.

This is less likely but not impossible for threads in kernel space - you can easily cause memory corruption or mess up memory mapped devices without triggering an instant crash.  The most likely crash that you'll generate in kernel space is by stomping on someone else's memory pointer and having them inadvertently step through it into unmapped space.

The major difference between userland and kernel really only relates to the scope of the damage you can do. Obviously in the kernel you can mess up a whole lot more.